# SQL-How to name and save a query table after it has been joined by another table?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to practice using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 on my own and I seem to have trouble understanding how to name and save a table after it has been joined by another table.  I tried to find similar examples online, but they were either not helpful or they created an error with my code.

Here is the code for my joined table:

```
CREATE TABLE students (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_name TEXT, last_name 
TEXT, email TEXT, phone TEXT, birthdate TEXT);

INSERT INTO students (id, first_name, last_name, email, phone, birthdate) 
VALUES (1, 'Peter', 'Rabbit', 'peter@rabbit.com', '555-6666', '2002-06-24');

INSERT INTO students (id, first_name, last_name, email, phone, birthdate) 
VALUES (2, 'Alice', 'Wonderland', 'alice@wonderland.com', '555-4444', '2002-
07-04');

CREATE TABLE student_grades (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, student_id INTEGER, 
test TEXT, grade INTEGER);

INSERT INTO student_grades (id, student_id, test, grade) VALUES (1, 1, 
'Nutrition', 95);

INSERT INTO student_grades (id, student_id, test, grade) VALUES (2, 2, 
'Nutrition', 92);

INSERT INTO student_grades (id, student_id, test, grade) VALUES (3, 1, 
'Chemistry', 85);

INSERT INTO student_grades (id, student_id, test, grade) VALUES (4, 2, 
'Chemistry', 95);
```

And here is the joined table code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student_grades
JOIN students 
ON student_grades.student_id = students.id
```

I have successfully been able to join these two tables together, but I seem to have trouble trying to name and save this new joined table called TableA.  It goes like this:

```
SELECT * INTO TableA
FROM student_grades
JOIN students 
ON student_grades.student_id = students.id
```

All that I get from the result is:

```
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'id' in table 
'TableA' is specified more than once.
```

I do not know why it is displaying this error.  Is my syntax correct and I am using the incorrect names, or is my syntax incorrect altogether?  Thanks for all possible responses.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 2 columns with the same name in a table; in your case [id]. Since student_id from student_grades table is the same as id from students table, you can disregard the latter. Please see query below.

```
SELECT  sg.[id] ,
        sg.[student_id] ,
        sg.[test] ,
        sg.[grade] ,
        s.[first_name] ,
        s.[last_name] ,
        s.[email] ,
        s.[phone] ,
        s.[birthdate]
INTO    TableA
FROM    student_grades sg
        JOIN students s ON sg.student_id = s.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the two tables have the field name "id" so you have to use alias name with the "id" field like below:

```
SELECT students.id as studentId, first_name, last_name, email, phone, birthdate
,student_grades.id as gradeId, test, grade INTO TableA
FROM student_grades
JOIN students 
ON student_grades.student_id = students.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I greatly appreciated it and everything runs correctly.